# Where does SVN store the data on the server side?

Tags: svn, fsfs

I have created an svn repo on my web host server and successfully commit files to it and updated files from it but I can't seem to actually find the files on the server!

My svn repo is in `~/svn/my-first-repo/` which contains the following: `./  ../  README.txt  conf/  db/  format  hooks/  locks/`.

**But where are the files I'm actually versioning?!**

It's definitely worked because I was able to checkout the same remote repo into another local directory and all the files magically appeared! As if from nowhere...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The files themselves are within the repository.  If you want to see them, then you need to perform a checkout.  Because subversion keeps complete change history for all files within your project, you will never see a fully reconstituted working copy underneath the repository's folder structure.

Basically, what's happening is a "versioned filesystem" that sits on top of your host filesystem.  You should probably read up on the [Subversion filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29#Filesystem) in more detail so you can understand exactly what is happening when you commit changes to your repository.

Answer (score 4):

SVN stores the versioned files in a database, not in the filesystem. So, it's all in there under the `db` directory. The specific database SVN uses is BerkeleyDB.

More information about SVN's backend storage can be found in t[he free online Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends).

Comment: The default backend for SVN these days is no longer BerkeleyDB, but FSFS.

Comment: I haven't been keeping up, I guess. I've moved over to git. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Look for the FSFS-structure. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/fsfs