# Automatically export contents of svn repository to another directory?

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn, svn-export

First, I would like to clarify a quick question I have, **am I right in thinking that files in svn repo don't actually exist in the heirarchical structure you see when you check them out**?

I have tried to use `svn export ~/svn/project1 ~/public_html/project1` but it didn't work.

What I actually want is to have the export command automatically executed when I do a commit so that I can see my changes immediately in a web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am I right in thinking that files in
>   svn repo don't actually exist in the
>   heirarchical structure you see when
>   you check them out

Correct... they actually exist in a DB of sorts in the repository directory. However you can invoke svn export on a working copy or a respoitory url. So lets say your repo is on the system at `/svn/myproject` and you have a working copy of `trunk` at `~/myproject` then either of the folloring commabds will export properly:

`svn export --force ~/myproject ~/public_html`

`svn export --force file:///svn/myproject/trunk ~/public_html`

ofcourse you can subsitute the `svn`, `http`, or `svn+ssh` for the `file` protocol depending on how your access is set up.

Comment: What specific problems does the `--force` deal wit? I had an issue with export already:

`svn export ~/public_html/svnmfr
svn: '/home/firefli/public_html/svnmfr' is not a working copy`

Comment: if `public_html` already exists the force flag will make the export overwrite it... otherwise it will complain that the directory already exists. The error you got means that whatever you tried to export wasnt in fact a subversion working copy - export is only invokable on working copies or a repository.

Comment: do a checkout. if its a public server though youll want to make the `.svn` directories unaccessible with a `.htaccess`

Comment: So I will have the actual versioned code in some folder, a checked out copy somewhere else on the server, _and_ a copy that's exported to public_html?

Comment: No, you don't make a checkout on the server.  You can export directly from the repository, which is what you want to do...not export from a working copy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; see [Where are my svn files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132947/where-are-my-svn-files)

Automatically exporting can be done with a [post-commit hook.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html)

Comment: Where do I put the post commit hook? I have a repo on a linux server and I'm committing to it from my windows box. I need the hook to export from the repo to another directory on the linux server.

Comment: @Matt:

Youll need access to svnadmin for that i think - are you an admin level user on this server or is svn running out of your user home?

Comment: svn is running from /home/user yeah